# Action that runs automatically when you open the django suit manager

Tags: python, django, django-suit

It is possible to perform an action automatically when opening the django suit administration panel, this in order to define specific tasks when the django suit main screen is opened, or when the screen of a specific model is loaded

Comment: What kind of action(s)?

Comment: Any action, for example when entering the main screen of a model, update a predefined field of all the values ​​entered, depending on the role of the user and the time at which he entered the view

Comment: So, logging of sorts?

Comment: [`django signals`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/) ?